# LDAP users can't login gnome but can with kde

Tags: gnome, openldap, opensuse

LDAP and NFS are working fine for KDE and SSH where users can log in without any problems. But only LDAP users can't login to GNOME desktop both directly or via NX client.

When logging in directly on the server it shows this error:

```
Xsession: Login for  is disabled
```

When logging via NX client it showed it authenticated successfully and then quited with this popup message:

```
Could not connect to session bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-0frstajyNE: Connection refused
```

I closed this popup window and one more appeared:

```
Could not acquire name on session bus
```

Tail 30 lines of /var/log/messages:

```
Apr 11 22:20:07 opensuse_11.4 sshd[5047]: error: Failed to allocate internet-domain X11 display socket.
Apr 11 22:20:08 opensuse_11.4 sshd[5123]: Accepted password for  from 127.0.0.1 port 46543 ssh2
Apr 11 22:20:08 opensuse_11.4 sshd[5127]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: disconnected by user
Apr 11 22:20:11 opensuse_11.4 sshd[5345]: Accepted password for  from 127.0.0.1 port 46547 ssh2
Apr 11 22:20:14 opensuse_11.4 kernel: [  508.616092] start_kdeinit (5654): /proc/5654/oom_adj is deprecated, please use /proc/5654/oom_score_adj instead.
Apr 11 22:20:30 opensuse_11.4 kernel: [  524.991957] fuse init (API version 7.15)
Apr 11 22:20:31 opensuse_11.4 pulseaudio[5787]: pid.c: Daemon already running.
Apr 11 22:20:48 opensuse_11.4 sshd[5347]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: disconnected by user
Apr 11 22:21:09 opensuse_11.4 sshd[5896]: Accepted publickey for nx from 
 port 52235 ssh2
Apr 11 22:21:09 opensuse_11.4 sshd[5898]: error: Failed to allocate internet-domain X11 display socket.
Apr 11 22:21:10 opensuse_11.4 sshd[5973]: Accepted password for  from 127.0.0.1 port 46564 ssh2
Apr 11 22:21:10 opensuse_11.4 sshd[5975]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: disconnected by user
Apr 11 22:21:13 opensuse_11.4 sshd[6193]: Accepted password for  from 127.0.0.1 port 46568 ssh2
Apr 11 22:21:15 opensuse_11.4 gnome-session[6458]: WARNING: Could not make bus activated clients aware of DISPLAY=:1080 environment variable: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-0frstajyNE: Connection refused
Apr 11 22:21:15 opensuse_11.4 gnome-session[6458]: WARNING: Could not make bus activated clients aware of GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated environment variable: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-0frstajyNE: Connection refused
Apr 11 22:21:15 opensuse_11.4 gnome-session[6458]: WARNING: Could not make bus activated clients aware of SESSION_MANAGER=local/opensuse_11.4:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/6458,unix/opensuse_11.4:/tmp/.ICE-unix/6458 environment variable: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-0frstajyNE: Connection refused
Apr 11 22:22:33 opensuse_11.4 gnome-session[6458]: Gtk-CRITICAL: IA__gtk_main_quit: assertion `main_loops != NULL' failed
Apr 11 22:22:33 opensuse_11.4 gnome-session[6458]: CRITICAL: dbus_g_proxy_new_for_name: assertion `connection != NULL' failed
Apr 11 22:23:00 opensuse_11.4 gnome-session[6458]: Gtk-CRITICAL: IA__gtk_main_quit: assertion `main_loops != NULL' failed
Apr 11 22:23:00 opensuse_11.4 gnome-session[6458]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Apr 11 22:23:00 opensuse_11.4 gnome-session[6458]: WARNING: keycode1 not existant
Apr 11 22:23:00 opensuse_11.4 gnome-session[6458]: WARNING: keycode2 not existant
Apr 11 22:23:00 opensuse_11.4 gnome-session[6458]: WARNING: GSIdleMonitor: IDLETIME counter not found
Apr 11 22:23:00 opensuse_11.4 gnome-session[6458]: CRITICAL: error getting session bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-0frstajyNE: Connection refused
Apr 11 22:23:00 opensuse_11.4 gnome-session[6458]: WARNING: Unable to register presence with session bus
Apr 11 22:23:00 opensuse_11.4 gnome-session[6458]: CRITICAL: dbus_g_proxy_new_for_name: assertion `connection != NULL' failed
Apr 11 22:23:00 opensuse_11.4 gnome-session[6458]: WARNING: Error retrieving configuration key '/desktop/gnome/session/idle_delay': Failed to contact configuration server; the most common cause is a missing or misconfigured D-Bus session bus daemon. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Failed to get connection to session: Error connecting: Connection refused)
Apr 11 22:23:00 opensuse_11.4 gnome-session[6458]: CRITICAL: error getting session bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-0frstajyNE: Connection refused
Apr 11 22:23:00 opensuse_11.4 sshd[6195]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: disconnected by user
Apr 11 22:24:26 opensuse_11.4 su: (to root)  on /dev/pts/2
```

Any advice/suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar problem on Centos 5.6.  The first problem I encountered was the inability for the gdm login screen to work with LDAP.

It turns out that gdm requires a secure connection to the LDAP server for login authentication, and it was failing because my self-signed cert wasn't trusted.

To get gdk to talk to my LDAP server in the first place, I put my LDAP server's self-signed certificate file in /etc/openldap/cacerts, then tweaked my /etc/ldap.conf file - I changed the URI line to use ldaps:// and port 636, and then added this line for the cert issue:

TLS_CACERT /etc/openldap/cacerts/ldap.pem

After solving that, I had an issue similar to what you are describing above, where upon login, I got a bunch of errors about not being able to connect to some socket in /tmp.  Prior to setting up LDAP auth, I had been using a local user account.  But, my posix uid and gid changed once I switched to using my LDAP server.  Fixing the ownership on everything in /tmp that had my old uid and gid fixed this issue for me.